# how to separate double values from string in Java

Tags: java, split

```
public class SplitTest { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String str = "32.85k"; 
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("k", 10); 

        for (String a : arrOfStr) 
            System.out.println(a); 
    } 
}
```

my output is 32.85K and I need my output as 32.85 and 'k' Separated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how to separate string into parts using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226518/java-how-to-separate-string-into-parts-using-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the string has `number dot number K` pattern,
you can just use `replace` method

```
String str = "32.85k"; 
String str2 = str.replace("k",""); // will return "32.85"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split using the following lookarounds:

```
(?<=\d)(?=[A-Za-z])
```

This says to split at any point in the string where what *precedes* is a digit and what *follows* is a lower/uppercase letter.

```
String str = "32.85k"; 
String[] arrOfStr = str.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])");

for (String a : arrOfStr)  {
    System.out.println(a); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex code to achieve,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String str = "32.85k";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the string is going to be one character long, you can use substring(0, length-1) for the double, and substring (length -1, length) for the String.

If you don’t know the string’s size, you will have to use Regex.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)(\.)")
while(m.find()){ 
    double d = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    String unity = m.group(2);
}
```